# collapse the rows with flatmap or reducedbyKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I got requirement to collapse the rows and have wrappedarray. here is original data and expected result. need to do it in spark scala.

Original Data:

```
Column1   COlumn2   Units   UnitsByDept
ABC       BCD       3       [Dept1:1,Dept2:2]
ABC       BCD       13      [Dept1:5,Dept3:8]
```

Expected Result:

```
ABC       BCD       16       [Dept1:6,Dept2:2,Dept3:8]
```

Comment: might want to add some more data. Eg dept 2

Comment: updated some more data

Comment: How is the data currently loaded in? Is it a dataframe? Do you have a code sample of what you've tried, and where you are stuck?

Comment: yes.. it is loaded into Dataframe

Comment: More understandable - indeed, but too late to answer! Except that Dept 1 appears in both rows...

Comment: @Ramana can you show us the example code of what you have, and where you're stuck? Consider following the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to give us a sample of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to use DataFrame APIs for what you need.  If you prefer using row-based functions like `reduceByKey`, here's one approach:

1. Convert the DataFrame to a PairRDD
2. Apply `reduceByKey` to sum up Units and aggregate UnitsByDept by Dept
3. Convert the resulting RDD back to a DataFrame:

Sample code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val df = Seq(
  ("ABC", "BCD", 3, Seq("Dept1:1", "Dept2:2")),
  ("ABC", "BCD", 13, Seq("Dept1:5", "Dept3:8"))
).toDF("Column1", "Column2", "Units", "UnitsByDept")

val rdd = df.rdd.
  map{ case Row(c1: String, c2: String, u: Int, ubd: Seq[String]) =>
    ((c1, c2), (u, ubd))
  }.
  reduceByKey( (acc, t) => (acc._1 + t._1, acc._2 ++ t._2) ).
  map{ case ((c1, c2), (u, ubd)) => 
    val aggUBD = ubd.map(_.split(":")).map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1).toInt)).
      groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum).
      map{ case (d, u) => d + ":" + u }
    ( c1, c2, u, aggUBD)
  }

rdd.collect
// res1: Array[(String, String, Int, scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String])] =
//   Array((ABC,BCD,16,List(Dept3:8, Dept2:2, Dept1:6)))  

val rowRDD = rdd.map{ case (c1: String, c2: String, u: Int, ubd: Array[String]) =>
  Row(c1, c2, u, ubd)
}

val dfResult = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, df.schema)

dfResult.show(false)
// +-------+-------+-----+---------------------------+
// |Column1|Column2|Units|UnitsByDept                |
// +-------+-------+-----+---------------------------+
// |ABC    |BCD    |16   |[Dept3:8, Dept2:2, Dept1:6]|
// +-------+-------+-----+---------------------------+
```

Comment: So, someone puts a -1 but does not say why. That is an issue with SO approach

Comment: @thebluephantom I suspect it's because the asker has a Dataframe, but the answer uses and RDD.

Comment: one can convert to RDD and back - if necessary. I have to say I have a lot of faith in Leo C. I am too old to have a hero, but I am improving my skills by looking at the advanced stuff he does, so I find it disrespectful given his track record. Anyway

Comment: It wasn't me, just what I suspect. I know some people also don't like code only answers, which could be another reason to downvote that. And a downvote on an answer isn't intended to be a besmirchment of character or skill of the answerer, it's just a statement on that one particular answer.

Comment: well i see it a little differently, but take your point. That said, the effort's benefit should be considered. Anyway, that's me